# linq to xml - get childrem of those nodes with a certain attribute

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML structure:

```
<partners>
  <partner partner="xxxxxx" Id="12345">
    <email>aa@aa.com</email>
    <email>bb@bb.com</email>
  </partner>
  <partner partner="yyyyyyy" Id="32165">
    <email>aa@aa.com</email>
    <email>bb@bb.com</email>
  </partner>
</partners>
```

I am trying to get all the email addresses of a certain partner from the ID, but can't quite get it.

I have tried this so far:

```
var x = from a in xdoc.Elements("partner") where a.Attribute("Id").Value == rpId.ToString() select a.Value;
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're just selecting the text within the relevant partner elements - and you'll end up with a *sequence* of results.

I think you want:

```
var query = xdoc.Root.Elements("partner")
                .Single(x => (string) x.Attribute("Id") == rpId.ToString())
                .Elements("email")
                .Select(x => x.Value);
```

This will fail if there are no elements with the given ID - or more than one. If you just want to find all the email addresses within all the matching elements, you can use:

```
var query = xdoc.Root.Elements("partner")
                .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Id") == rpId.ToString())
                .Elements("email")
                .Select(x => x.Value);
```

EDIT: I've changed `xdoc.Elements` to `xdoc.Root.Elements` given the comments; I suspect you have:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(...);
```

That means that `xdoc.Elements(...)` can only find the root element - whereas you want to search *from* the root element.

Comment: hmmm - it is an empty sequence even if I reduce the query to just the following: var query = xdoc.Elements("partner").Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Id") == rpId.ToString())

Comment: @ChrisCa: Then that suggests there are no appropriate `partner` elements. There are any number of potential reasons for that, but I can't check any of them from here. First thing to check - that you're getting `partner` elements at all. Remove the `Where` clause and see what happens. Next, check the `Id` attributes, and `rpId` itself...

Comment: in fact, even this is empty: var query = xdoc.Elements("partner");

Comment: @ChrisCa: Then that suggests that `xdoc` is an `XDocument` instead of an `XElement` for the root node, so you probably want `xdoc.Root.Elements("partner")`. (This is where it would be much simpler if you'd provided a short but complete program to start with.)

Comment: you are right, xdoc is an Xdocument (hence the variables name). But a more complete code snippet would have helped, for sure